# fixing label overlapping in second level of grouped categories plugin used in highchart

Tags: highcharts

[image]

In the above highchart, the label in the second level appears to move out of bounds which could overlap the "Vegetable" unlike the label in the first level preceeded with " ...." is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a useHTML flag and use CSS styles for labels.

```
   .highcharts-axis-labels.highcharts-xaxis-labels > span {
            word-break: break-all!important;
            white-space: normal!important;
        width:80px!important;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TFhd7/533/